# How could I use classes in Python 3 to increase functionality of my program?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, rfid

I'm trying to write a simple Python program (using this wrapper: https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi) that can store rfid properties. I did this successfully using a dictionary, but I would like to make my own class so I could add more information to the class instead of just a key and value as is the case with the python dictionary. The tag epc (electronic product code) is used as the "key", and the rssi-value (the signal strength) is used as the "value" in the dictionary.

This is my code thusfar:

```
# Importing modules
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import mercury

# Variables
protocol = "GEN2"
region  = "EU3"
reader_power = 2000
count = 0
all_reads = {}
final_reads = []

# Trying different USB connections for the RFID-reader, gives an error if nothing is found
try:
    reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyACM1", baudrate=115200)
except TypeError:
    try:
        reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=115200)
    except TypeError:
        reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200)
    except:
        raise TypeError('RFID-reader not found, check ls /dev/')

def test_func(tag):
    if str(tag.epc) not in all_reads.keys():
        all_reads[str(tag.epc)] = int(tag.rssi)

    else:
        if int(tag.rssi) > all_reads[str(tag.epc)]:
            print("should update for epc = ", tag.epc, "old rssi = ", all_reads[str(tag.epc)], "with new rssi = ", tag.rssi)
            all_reads.update({str(tag.epc): int(tag.rssi)})

# Mandatory sets for the reader
reader.set_region(region) # Setting the correct region
reader.set_read_powers([1, 2], [reader_power, reader_power]) # Setting the reader power
reader.set_read_plan([1, 2], protocol) # Setting the correct  RFID-reading protocol

#Start rfid Reading
reader.start_reading(lambda tag: test_func(tag))
time.sleep(5)
reader.stop_reading()
print(all_reads)
```

Most parts of the code aren't really that interesting, they are just mandatory parts so the rfid-reader can function. Like importing the correct libraries, trying to connect to the correct usb device etc. The function definition: test_func(tag) is where the logic really starts. It first checks if the newly read epc is available as a key in the dictionary all_reads. If it isn't available, then the epc is added as a key in combination with the rssi-value as a value to the dictionary. If the epc is already in the dictionary, then the program checks if a new better rssi value is found, and updates the dictionary if this is the case. This outputs something along the lines of:

```
should update for epc =  b'E20000000000000000000003' old rssi =  -46 with new rssi =  -45
should update for epc =  b'E20000000000000000000000' old rssi =  -50 with new rssi =  -49
should update for epc =  b'E20000000000000000000002' old rssi =  -41 with new rssi =  -40
should update for epc =  b'E20000000000000000000001' old rssi =  -36 with new rssi =  -35
should update for epc =  b'E20000000000000000000000' old rssi =  -49 with new rssi =  -47
should update for epc =  b'E20000000000000000000000' old rssi =  -47 with new rssi =  -43
{"b'E20000000000000000000003'": -45, "b'E20000000000000000000002'": -40, "b'E20000000000000000000000'": -43, "b'E20000000000000000000001'": -35}
```

This all works fine, you get one object with individual epc with the best rssi value, but I would like to have the option to add more information per epc "key". So I thought that the solution would be creating my own class. I tried recreating me previously described code behaviour with a self made class: This is my attempt at doing that:

```
class tags:
    def __init__(self, epc, rssi):
        self.epc = epc
        self.rssi = rssi
```

How could I recreate behaviour with a selfmade class? Storing the "tags" classes in a similar fashion way as with the dictionary?

Any helps is much appreciated!

Comment: Advices: 1. If ain't broke, don't fix it. 2. This should be posted in [codereviews](https://codereviews.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @yorodm in its current state, it's off-topic on Code Review. Asking for new features or rewrites in other paradigms is off-topic. The code is fine for a general review, although the description needs to get extended for CR.SE.